# How to get PrimaryClusterId from CfnReplicationGroup in aws cdk

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cdk, amazon-elasticache

I have created global datastore(Test-Replication-group) using cdk
and it has 1 primary node and second is replica node
Test-Replication-group-001
Test-Replication-group-002

So how can I access this 2 node using cdk(typescript)

Comment: People will be better able to provide help if you [provide code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.